# HR Director returning to career after 8 years

Tags: resume, human-resources, career-switch

I left my HR career to move overseas and marry my husband. I have worked (teaching) but not in the HR profession as it has been too difficult to find an HR position.

Now, 8 years later we will be returning to the US. I would love to return to my HR career, but it is very difficult to apply for any entry position as I am overqualified and out of date.

I know I remember everything from HR like the back of my hand. How can I return back to the workforce, or what is the best approach? I do have 5 years of previous HR experience and a Masters in HR. I held teaching positions during my overseas years.

Answer (score 4):

Your assessment that you are overqualified for an entry level position is  probably exact.

You seem to be confident that you can fulfill the Director of HR position, provided that you meet the objection that you haven't done this work for years.

I'd say that eight years have passed and you probably need to make the extra effort to keep up to date with the changes that have taken place over the last eight years. Being up to date, if nothing else, makes you a credible candidate.

For you re-entry job, you may have to target those organizations that require a Director of HR but can't afford one. You may not get the salary you want but as long as you can point out to your next prospective employer that you have been fulfilling the responsibilities of a Director of HR, you have a fighting chance of getting your career back on track.

You're trying to do a lot more than just getting hired, you're trying to rebuild your career and rebuilding your career may very well be a process that takes place over several jobs. You need to think long term while doing what it takes to get through the short term.

Comment: This is a good idea. OP could also find a "Director of HR" at a much smaller organization, where they might not have the same responsibilities from 8 years ago but more than entry level responsibilities.